# Static block setting Calendar for usage in assignment - dates

Tags: java, date, calendar, final

I currently have the following code, which doesn't work correctly since I suspect my `static block` is not being called before my assignment of `programCutoffDate2015`.

```
private final static Calendar programCutoffDate2015Cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    static{
        programCutoffDate2015Cal.set(2015, 12,31);
    }
    private final static Date programCutoffDate2015 = programCutoffDate2015Cal.getTime();
```

Previously I was using the deprecated API:

```
private final static Date programCutoffDate2015 = new Date(2015, 12,31);
```

How should I accomplish the same result using the newer API that is not deprecated within the JDK?

Comment: What do you mean by "the new API"? Do you mean the one introduced in Java 1.1, or the one introduced in Java 8? (The `java.util.Date` API is horribly *horribly* broken, btw. The `java.util.Calendar` API is bad too, but slightly less so...)

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks for the comment... I didn't check the actual dates of the API changes and strangely never came across this issue.  I will update my question to 'newer'. I think I will switch to Joda Time then. Also for all those downvoting... if it happened to me it could happen to others. It's not obvious if you haven't used the Date libraries all that much. I can only wonder what the original developers were thinking !?!

Comment: @JonSkeet Internally, GregorianCalendar has 27 fields, many of them arrays. One class trying to do too much I suspect. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Oh the implementation may well be absolutely horrible, yes. And the mutable design still leaves a lot to be desired... it's just nicer than `Date`, IMO :)

Comment: I suspect the downvotes may have been partly due to the last sentence, which seems to be dismissive of the API designers without understanding the issues of the `Date` class. I suggest you remove that last sentence entirely, as it really doesn't add anything to your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet if you serialize a GregorianCalendar and deserialize it, it uses around 3KB and takes around 50 micro-seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Date` has no concept of time zone and is mutable. It has been widely coincided a poor API for the last tens years or so. I suggest using the JSR 310 API, added to Java 8 but [backports](http://www.threeten.org/) for older versions are available.

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2015,12,31);
```

Note: while this is based on the good work in JodaTime, it is a different API.

> Is there any way to have that static block executed before the declaration of programCutoffDate2015 or another way?

static blocks execute in order they appear in the code, top to bottom. There is no way to change this even if multiple threads attempt to load the class at the same time.

Say you had another API which had the problem you have above, I would suggest wrapping this with a helper method.

```
private static Date newDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month, day);
    // if you want the last milli-second of the day for an upper bound
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -1);
    return cal.getTime();
}

private final static Date programCutoffDate2015 = newDate(2015, 12, 31);
```

Or even better

```
private static LcoalDate lastDayOf(int year) {
    return LocalDate.of(year+1, 1, 1).minusDays(1);
}
```

A significant difference between `Date` and `LocalDate` is the Date has a time included though this is perhaps not intended as `2015/12/31 12:00` would be after your `Date` object yet still in 2015.  `LocalDate` is just a date, if you want a time as well you can use `LocalDateTime`